# problems with windwows authentication using sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem. I have problems with authentication in sharepoint. For login, we have two different authentications: 1. forms authentication for customers 2. windows authentication for employees.
forms authentication for customers works with the following code:

```
  using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://project.com/blabla"))
            {

                //forms authentication 1
                clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
                clientContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
               Web w = clientContext.Web;
  List announcementsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Cars");

                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query);




                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

We need windows authentication for employees of the organisation. I'm getting an error with the following code:

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://project.com/blabla"))
 {
        //windows authentcation 
                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential           (txtUsername.Text, txtPassowrd.Text, "DOMAIN");
     List announcementsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Cars");

                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query);

                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

the error message when using windows authentication is: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

has anyone a solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using windows auth then how did you get their password?  The whole point of using window's auth is that *you never need to touch their password*.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might come from default impersonation settings trying to use the system account.

Please check this is set to false in your application's settings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:AllowAnonymousImpersonation" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks fine to me, is your domain inputs correct?

```
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassowrd.Text, "DOMAIN");
```

test using this syntax:

```
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"DOMAIN\"+txtUsername.Text, txtPassowrd.Text);
```

Comment: this is not a wrong explanation, shouldn't get -1 vote!